# Creating df, comparing to existing excel data, if there then ignoring, if not there then adding to bottom of excel - Pandas/Python

Tags: pandas, excel

I am pulling data from a website and pushing it to an excel file in python via pandas. The next time I pull the data, I want it to compare the new data to what is in the excel. If it's there, then I want it to do nothing. If it's not there, I want it to add to the bottom of the list in excel. I can't seem to get a code to continuously ADD rather than overwrite. I can get it to add once and then it starts overwriting. The other issue I'm encountering is having it compare to the excel and only add if it's not already there. Help?

**Here is my original code:**

```
reschedules = pd.DataFrame(df)
orders = reschedules["Order #"]

if os.path.exists("reschedules.xlsx"):
    addresses = pd.read_excel("reschedules.xlsx")
else:
    addresses = pd.DataFrame(reschedules, columns=["Order #", "Account", "Address"]) 
    addresses.to_excel("reschdeules.xlsx", index=False)

for order in orders:
    address = order.split("<br>")[0]
    if address not in addresses["Order #"].values:
        addresses = addresses.append({"Order #": address}, ignore_index=True)
        addresses.to_excel("reschedules.xlsx", index=False)
        print(addresses)
```

**Here is what I was able to get to work once or twice before it started overwriting the excel again:**

```
reschedules = pd.DataFrame(df)
builderorders = reschedules["Order #"]

if os.path.exists("reschedules.xlsx"):
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
    wb = load_workbook("reschedules.xlsx")
    ws = wb['Sheet1']
    for row in dataframe_to_rows(reschedules):
        ws.append(row)

else:
    addresses = pd.DataFrame(reschedules, columns=["Order #", "Account", "Address"])  
    addresses.to_excel("reschdeules.xlsx", index=False)
```